# How to keep alive the tcp listener to avoid error - unable to write data to transport connection?

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I want to keep alive the TCP listener to avoid connection loss. How to make the TCP listener alive for 12 hours?

Below Code:

```
 TcpListener tcp = new TcpListener(port);
        tcp.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");
            TcpClient client = tcp.AcceptTcpClient();
            client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000000;

            // Gets the receive time out using the ReceiveTimeout public property.
            if (client.ReceiveTimeout > 5000000)
                Console.WriteLine("The receive time out limit was successfully set " + client.ReceiveTimeout.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            try
            {
                String request = sr.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(request);
                string strValue = request;
            }   
     }
```

[image: Error screen shot]

Comment: Sockets die, ultimately. Is this failure after a long period of inactivity? Or...? Note: ReadLine (and sync IO in general) is very bad scalability wise; how many sockets do you need to support here? (right now, your server scales to one client)

Comment: after 2 hours its throwing error , if there is no connection connected. is it possible to increase the active time period?

Comment: What is curious here is: the exception you've shown in the image is happening in `Stream.Write`; you don't *have* any "write" code in the fragment you've shown. Is that error *actually* happening from the code you've shown? You also have a `try` without a `catch` or `finally`, which isn't valid C#. This makes it very hard to comment with much strength

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you're writing to a socket that turns out to be dead. This is normal and expected in anything socket-related, and in many cases the *only way to properly detect* that a socket is dead: is to try reading from / writing to it, so: you should *expect* any socket operation to fail, and handle it. As for keeping a socket alive; the best way to do that is to periodically (say, every five minutes, or one minute, or whatever you want) send a dummy message backwards and forwards. This achieves two goals:

1. it can help the OS and other software realise that the socket is still in use, and not tear it down
2. if the socket *does* fail for any reason, it means you can detect it by tracking when the last message was seen, and if it has missed a couple of heartbeats: assume the worst